# Javascript no funciona en mobile pero si en desktop

Tags: javascript, prestashop1.7

Buenas tardes valiosa comunidad. Tengo un problema en el **JS** en dos funciones. Cabe aclarar que funciona con total normalidad en ***browser desktop***, pero en **mobile** no funciona. Problema: cuando agrego UN producto al carrito en `mobile view`, el contador del carrito se incrementa en +10, el precio total también. Las funciones son las siguientes:

```
function carttotalamount() {
svar productsArray = [];
var sum = 0;
var totalItems = 0;
var totalQuantity = 0;
var test1 = 1;
$("#cspositionstatic  .productrow").each(function( i ) {
    $(this).addClass("pktestdemo"+test1);

    productsArray.push($(this).attr("product"));

    var price = $(this).find(".cspricecrt").val();
    var WithoutCPrice = price.replace("$", "");
    WithoutCPrice = parseFloat(WithoutCPrice.replace(",", "."));

    var qty = $(this).attr("quantity");
    var productPrice = parseFloat(qty * WithoutCPrice);
    sum += Number(productPrice);
    totalQuantity += parseInt(qty);
    totalItems++;
    test1++;
});

$(".cart-products-count").html(totalItems);

sum = parseFloat(sum);
if(sum <= 0) {
    $(".continue-btn").addClass("disable");
} else {    
    $(".continue-btn").removeClass("disable");
}   

var totalprice = String(sum.toFixed(2));
$(".amount.pull-right").html("$ "+totalprice.replace(".", ","));
$("#previewcarttotal").html("$ "+totalprice.replace(".", ","));

if(document.getElementById("previewcarttotal")){
    if(sum >= 90){
        document.getElementById("myCartBar").style.width = "90%";
        document.getElementById("freeshipmsg").innerText = "¡Felicitaciones! El envio de tu compra es GRATIS";
        document.getElementById("freeship-icon-pump").style.display = "block";          
    }else{
        document.getElementById("myCartBar").style.width = (sum * 90)/90 + '%';
        document.getElementById("freeshipmsg").innerText = "Superando los $90, tu envio es GRATIS";
        document.getElementById("freeship-icon-pump").style.display = "none";
    }
}

if(sum <= 0){
    $('.cart-products-count').html('0');
    $('.cs-no-item-message').show();
    $('.cart-footer').show();
    $('#freeshipmsg').hide();
    $('#myCartProgress').hide();
    $('#previewcarttotal').html('0');
}else{
    $('.cart-products-count').html(totalQuantity);
    $('.cs-no-item-message').hide();
    $('.cart-footer').show();
    $('#freeshipmsg').show();
    $('#myCartProgress').show();
 }
}
```

Comment: ¿Con qué navegadores de móvil no te funciona? Defines lo que ocurre en tu dispositivo móvil, pero no defines el comportamiento esperado. Si realmente deseas que tu problema sea resuelto te recomiendo que publiques un ejemplo en JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/), JSBin (https://jsbin.com/?html,output) o alguna web similar, porque solo con ese fragmento de JavaScript y la información aportada es un poco complicado ayudarte

Comment: Hola Roberto! gracias por contestar. No funciona en ningun navegador mobile.  El codigo se puede ver en: https://jsfiddle.net/andresmatiasc/5tLxzu2f/2/#&togetherjs=EBx90CaTnD

Comment: Hola Andrés :), gracias por aportar el ejemplo en jsFiddle, pero no has puesto HTML en el enlace que has pasado, solo se ve una pantalla en blanco

Comment: Hola Roberto! No puedo ingresar HTML porque es un prestashop y compila todo a .tpl. El error es 100% que esta en esas dos funciones.

Comment: Tienes al menos una URL pública accesible? El comportamiento esperado sería incrementar en uno el contador del carrito y no incrementar el precio? Para cargar el HTML puedes inspeccionar la página una vez compilada y construir a partir de ella un ejemplo mínimo. Viendo el código y suponiendo que no has cometido errores de sintaxis (como el svar productsArray que debe ser un var productsArray) estás utilizando código compatible con todos los navegadores, por eso creo que quizás falta algo. Podría entender que funcionara o que no, pero es complicado que ese código falle en función del navegador.